# Finding Smallest and Largest in an array in MIPS?

Tags: assembly, mips

I have to make a program for my course that will search through an array of integers and output the smallest and largest integers in the array in MIPS.

For the output, I just get 0 for both the maximum and minimum.

Why is this happening?

```
    .data
    intArray: .word 3, 53, -76, 34, 643, -234, 143, 2, -33, 64
    floatArray: .float 43.53, 45.2244, 25, 64.035, 328, 23.85, 23.86544, 93.4, 46.6543256, 0.00345
    intMinOut: .asciiz "The smallest number in the integer array is: "
    intMaxOut: .asciiz "The largest number in the integer array is: "
.text

main:
    la $t0, intArray
    addi $t1, $zero, 9 
    addi $t2, $zero, 0
    sw $t3, intArray($zero)
    sw $t5, intArray($zero)

    findSmallest:
        beqz $t1, findLargest
        sub $t1, $t1, 1
        blt $t5, $t3, intSmaller 
        addi $t2, $t2, 1
        j findSmallest

    intSmaller:
        lw $t4, intArray($t2) 
        move $t3, $t4 
        addi $t2, $t2, 1 
        j findSmallest 

    findLargest:
        addi $t1, $zero, 9
        addi $t2, $zero, 0
        intLgLoop:
            beqz $t1, print 
            sub $t1, $t1, 1
            bgt $t3, $t5, intLarger
            addi $t2, $t2, 1
            j intLgLoop

    intLarger:
        lw $t4, intArray($t2)
        move $t5, $t4
        addi $t2, $t2, 1
        j intLgLoop

    print:
        la $a0, intMinOut
        li $v0, 4
        syscall
        move $a0, $t3
        li $v0, 1
        syscall
        la $a0, intMaxOut
        li $v0, 4
        syscall
        move $a0, $t5
        li $v0, 1
        syscall
        b end

end:
    .macro done
    li $v0, 10
    syscall
    .end_macro
    done
```

Comment: `sw $t3, intArray($zero)` and `sw $t5, intArray($zero)` is super weird.  Why are you storing two uninitialized registers over the first element of your array?  The 1st store is completely useless because the 2nd one overwrites it right away.  (In compiler / optimization terminology, it's a dead store).  Did you maybe mean to use `lw` to load a word?  Have you single-stepped your code in a debugger to watch how register values change?

Comment: Oh, I think I had it backwards, I meant to store the first element of the integer array in both $t3 and $t5 (not move it, but just "copy" it). I tried reversing it, and then I tried using lw, however, now I'm getting the error that "intArray" operand is of incorrect type. Do you know why this is? Thank you for your help!

Comment: That's called *loading*.  When memory is the source of a copy, it's a load.  Try to avoid saying "store to a register", because that will just get you thinking backwards in terminology.  But anyway, `lw` and `sw` both use the same `op  reg, mem`  syntax, even though for `sw` that means the source is first, unlike all other instructions.  That's just a quirk of MIPS source-level syntax; the machine encoding for LW and SW is of course similar, both being I-type instructions.  If I were designing the syntax, I'd have made it `sw intArray($zero), $t3` vs. `lw $t3, intArray($zero)`.